# Open map and adherence

Tags: general-topology, analysis

How to prove that $$f :E\rightarrow F ~\text{is open} \Longleftrightarrow f^{-1}(\overline{A})\subset \overline{f^{-1}(A)}, \forall A\subset F$$

where $(E,\tau), (F,\theta)$ are topological spaces.

My problem is how to apply that $f$ is open when we have $\overline{A}$ witch is a closed set.

Thank you

Comment: So you are confused about the $\implies$ direction, right?

Comment: also the second if i take an open set $A$ i have that $\overset{º}{A}=A$ and $A\subset \overline{A}$ nothing elsse !

Comment: Check out my answer for the $\implies$ direction and see if it gives you any ideas for the $\impliedby$ direction.

Answer (score 1):

For the $\implies$ direction:

Suppose $f$ is an open map.  Then if $U \subseteq E$ is open, $f(U) \subseteq F$ is open.

We want to show for all $A \subseteq F$, $f^{-1}(\overline{A}) \subseteq \overline{f^{-1}(A)}$.

Let $A \subseteq F$.  If $x \in f^{-1}(\overline{A})$, then $f(x) \in \overline{A}$.  But $f(x) \in \overline{A} \implies$ for every open $V$ with $f(x) \in V$, $V \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

Suppose by contradiction that $x \not \in \overline{f^{-1}(A)}$.  Then there is some open $U$ such that $x \in U$ and $U \cap f^{-1}(A) = \emptyset$.  But $x \in U$ implies $f(x) \in f(U)$.  Since $f$ is an open map, $f(U)$ is open.  Since $U \cap f^{-1}(A) = \emptyset$, no element of $U$ is being mapped into $A$, so $f(U) \cap A = \emptyset$.  But then we found an open neighborhood of $f(x)$ that does not intersect $A$, so $f(x) \not \in \overline{A}$, which means $x \not \in f^{-1}(\overline{A})$, which is a contradiction to what we initially assumed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i understand it but for the inverse implication, i don't have idea, if i say let $A$ an open subset of $E$ and we want prove that $f(A)$ is open but i dont know how we introduce $f^{-1}(\overline{B})\subset...$

Comment: @Vrouvrou I'm not quite sure how to solve the other direction.  I've tried multiple routes but haven't been able to do it yet.  If I figure it out, I'll update my answer.